# How to create gstreamer plugin for identifying private stream in mpeg2ts?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, mpeg2-ts

I am sending some vendor-specific information in the PES packet with a private stream type of 0xBD. I am packetizing this into a new TS Packet PID.

How can I demux this packet and use that data on the GStreamer decoding side?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stream type identication:
   You can make changes in 'tsdemux' gstreamer bad plugin to identify the custom stream type (0xBD) and demux the packet. Look into [tsdemux.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/gst/mpegtsdemux/tsdemux.c) to get details about stream type identification.
2. Pass custom data from demuxer to decoder: 
   There are multiple ways you can achieve this in gstreamer. Here is a good explanation related to this: [more info](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/how-to-pass-custom-metadata-between-gst-elements-td2271826.html)